# Bootstrap - How to move indicators out of the main div

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have multiple carousels in one page. I need to move Indicators out of the main carousel div. Everything works but when I click on indicator it did not activated.

```
 <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

<div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">    
  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: indicators should be place on carousel div

Answer (score 0):

It will works

```
 <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">    

<!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="..." alt="...">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can put your indicators in any `div` and just move it using CSS properties, f.e.:

```
.indicators {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```